# How to change $scope variable from a modal window

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have this function inside my controller to which I send a series of data that I receive as parameters correctly.

```
$scope.changeValues = function(measure,name,valCol) {

var modalInstance = $modal.open({

    templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',

    backdrop: 'static',

    scope: $scope, 

    controller: function($scope, $modalInstance) {

             $scope.ok = function(){

                 $scope.myVar = "hello";
                 console.log($scope.myVar);
                 modalInstance.close();

             }

    }

});};
```

I want to change the value of the $scope.myVar variable in my $modal.window, but these changes are not saved. Where is the error?

```
<div class="reducedfont" ng-init="loadCtrl()">

<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
<!-- template for modal -->
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">{{valueName}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">Ok</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div></script>
<p>{{myVar}}</p>
```

Comment: `not saved` ?? Where? Provide a plunkr to have a quick solution

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change the

```
 $scope.changeValues = function(measure,name,valCol) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({

        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',

        backdrop: 'static',

        scope: $scope, 

        controller: function($scope, $modalInstance) {

                 $scope.ok = function(){

                     $scope.myVar = "hello";
                     console.log($scope.myVar);
                     $modalInstance.close($scope.myVar);

                 }

        }

    })//end of $model


    modalInstance.result.then(function (SelectedItem) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            //SelectedItem is the value return from modal controller on close and $scope.myVar is the variable in the controller where $scope.changeValues function is defined.

            $scope.myVar= SelectedItem;
        }, 500);
    });

    };//end of function
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you are doing well but in a wrong way.

If you want to keep the updated value you have to set it as an **object property value**.

Working with string (or in general with primitives type) breaks the object reference between your scopes.

Try with:

```
controller: function($scope) {

    $scope.ok = function(){

        $scope.myVar.value = "hello";

        console.log($scope.myVar);
        modalInstance.close();
    }
}
```

When you will be out of your modal (and when its scope is destroyed) your **$scope.myVar** will keeping that property *value* with the update.